# Weird behaviour of TransformedRegion and GeometricTransformation

Tags: computational-geometry, geometric-transform, polyhedra

What I would like to do is to take some polyhedra (such as `Cuboid`s, `Prism`s, and `Parallelipiped`s), rotate and reflect them around the origin, and afterward do some geometric computations such as `RegionIntersection` and `Volume`. However, sometimes the transformation simply... doesn't happen? For instance, the following commands basically return their input:

```
p = Parallelepiped[{1.,0.,0.}, {{-1.,1.,0.}, {0.,1.,0.}, {0.,0.,1.}}]
TransformedRegion[p, RotationTransform[0, {1, 1, 1}]]
GeometricTransformation[p, RotationTransform[0, {1, 1, 1}]]
```

Strangely, it seems that if I wrap these in `Graphics3D` then they render exactly as they are supposed to be; also, it seems that sometimes this code *does* work, for instance for `TransformedRegion[Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}], RotationTransform[Pi/2, {0, 0, 1}]]`. Is there some way of writing transformations which always works? Or is this a bug in Mathematica? Currently if I try to use one of these not-transformed regions in, for instance, `RegionIntersection` Mathematica complains that it is not a correctly formed region (presumably since it still has head `TransformedRegion`).

Comment: Try a `30°` rotation, e.g: `TransformedRegion[p, RotationTransform[30 Degree, {1, 1, 1}]]`. The region stays the same when rotated by `0°`.

Comment: @Syed yes that works in this instance but my code creates various polyhedra and rotates/reflects them at various angles and through various planes so I need a general solution. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: @LiamBaker `RotationTransform[0, {1, 1, 1}]` is identity transformation. Though what do you expect from your example???

Comment: @UlrichNeumann in this case I would expect it to just return `p`

Comment: @CarlWoll I'm using 13.3.1.0

Comment: The first line in the Details section of `GeometricTransformation` states: "`GeometricTransformation[g, ...]` remains unchanged under evaluation, but affects how `g` is rendered."

Comment: I get a Parallelepiped object when evaluating your TransformedRegion call in versions 12.1 to 13.3.1.

Comment: Apologies everyone, I realised that the cases I had where the code was bugging out was where the polyhedron was degenerate. So I guess this question is 'wrong' in some sense. Should I delete it?